# Display the first row in each group

Tags: reporting-services

I have problem to display the first row in in each group in Reporting Service.

```
City     Name     Cash
----------------------
Boston   James     10
      Mattias    5
      Adam       4

LA    Sara      34
      Sakura    23

NY    Melissa   69
      Jessica   34
```

I have used group on in row groups at Column City.

The requested result would be:

```
City     Name      Cash
-----------------------
Boston   James      10
LA    Sara       34
NY    Melissa    69
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the columns in your Grouping Row rather than the City in your Group Row and the name, Cash Amt in the Details.  Like so:

[image]

This way, it will display only the first one in the group:

[image]

Here is the simple dataset I used if you want to mess around with it:

```
select 'Computers' as Section, 'Mark' as EmpName, '10' as Cash union
select 'Mobile' as Section, 'Mary' as EmpName, '20' as Cash union
select 'Computers' as Section, 'Tom' as EmpName, '5' as Cash union
select 'Computers' as Section, 'Dave' as EmpName, '40' as Cash union
select 'Mobile' as Section, 'John' as EmpName, '15' as Cash
```

Of course remember how you ORDER BY or set up the sorting in the report will determine who shows up.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to make use of the `TOP N` function for creating a filter for your groups.

Microsoft's technet page: [Filter Equation Examples (Report Builder 3.0 and SSRS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627464.aspx)

Tutorial on how to filter with `TOP N`: [Display Top N Rows](http://jessicammoss.blogspot.com/2008/08/display-top-n-rows.html)